# How can I display text when a input field from a while loop is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, text

What I want is when i click a input field to display a div below that input.I managed to display the div with javascript, but it only works for the first input from the loop.
How can I display that div for every intput that is clicked?
Thanks!

```
    <script>
                function showDiv() {
       document.getElementById('div_to_show').style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
<php
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <div id="div_to_show"  style="display:none;"><a href="#">LINK</a></div>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php$row_['name'];?>" onclick="showDiv()"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: i only see one div in the code you posted. if you have more than one div, please post them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element ID must be unique. If you use function `getElementById`, it will find only one element. Try this code:

```
    <script>
                function showDiv(i) {
       document.getElementById('div_to_show'+i).style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
<php
$i=0;
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <div id="div_to_show<?php echo $i;?>"  style="display:none;"><a href="#">LINK</a></div>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php$row_['name'];?>" onclick="showDiv(<?php echo $i;?>)"/>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

This way your divs will have ids div_to_show0, div_to_show1, etc.